# Address already in use when use static_fields in Beats in Graylog 4.2

Tags: filebeat, graylog, elastic-beats

I am experiencing a strange issue with Graylog. When attempting to use "static_fields" on Beats as an input, I am encountering an "address already in use" error.Can you please advise on how to troubleshoot and resolve this issue? Thank you.

(if I remove static_fields content , the graylog and beats work correctly)

os : ubuntu 22.04
graylog version : 4.2
elasticsearch : 7.10.2
mongo : 4.4.24

I have tried adding a static field using the Graylog input feature, but it does not seem to resolve the issue.

[image]

[image]